# MongoDB - Create object with reference manually - DBRef doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, reference, foreign-keys, database

for testing purposes I need to create manually some objects in a MongoDB. My Class has a reference field to another class. The referred object already exists.

I tried to put the Mongo-ID of my existing object as a value in my new object but I get the following error:

> A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef: ['attribute'])

**Now my question: Where do I get or find this `DBRef`?**

---

An example:
I have a user in my db. I want to create a group which has the existing user as `"creator"`. When I put the user-ID into the creator-field I get the error...

Edit:

I just found this link [MongoDB - DBRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713304/mongodb-dbref) but the solution does not work for me...

```
item : {"$ref" : "fruit", "$id" : "1"}
```

My code is like this:

```
{ "name" : "MyGroup", "created_at" : "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "creator": { "$ref": "user", "$id": "501bd5ac32f28a1278e54435" } }
```

Another edit:

Even the Mongo doc says I'm using the right format... http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON. But still not working.

Comment: What language/framework are you using?

Comment: Django and MongoEngine... but I create the object (its just for testing) via the shell

Comment: I have the following (based on the link i posted above): {"name" : "MyGroup", "created_at" : "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "creator": { "$ref": "user", "$id": "501bd5ac32f28a1278e54435" } }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713304/162228), the user is using a numeric string as their document ID. In your case, it looks like you're working with the more-common ObjectId but inserting it as a string. Assuming you're using PyMongo, you probably want to use the [ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) class for the `$id` property of the [DBRef](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/dbref.html).

If you know all such references are going to point to the same DB and collection, it may make sense to use manual references (just storing the target document's `_id`) instead of DBRef objects. This is explained in more detail in the [Database References documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/).